# kindle not connecting to wi-fi

Tags: kindle, wifi

Whenever I am trying to connect my kindle to wi-fi it shows no internet found. Once my kindle got discharged to 0. So is that the reason why my kindle is not able to find any internet. If no, then why my kindle is not able to find any internet? And if yes, then what should I do so that it finds wi-fi again.
This question is a duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230597/334985

Comment: Have you tried Settings >> Device >> Wireless & Bluetooth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I don't think it's because of your kindle discharged to 0. Many times my kindle also goes to Zero percentage but it connected to wifi again once I charge my kindle. If you can reset your kindle I think it might solve your issue. Please find the link to how to Reset your kindle.
https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-reset-kindle-paperwhite?IR=T

Comment: since kindle is not connected to wifi will the kindle be able to remember all the books saved by my account? I mean that wifi is not on so maybe it might not remember the books I have and so by relogging in kindle it might shows 0 books installed

Comment: All the books will be saved into your amazon account. You can check by login into your **Amazon account > Your Account > Manage Your Content and Devices > Show Books and select Purchases**. Here you can look at all your saved books.

Comment: When I went to the location specified by you I found this https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Goa.png. Here it is showing no book. Should I try to sign in to amazon.in and then see books?

Comment: Yes you need to sign in with your Amazon account and with that email I’d only which you have registered in your kindle account.

Comment: If I reset my devices and log in again will I be able to see all the books I downloaded before resetting? Just the last question

Comment: Yes, you will be able to see all the books. As it’s restored in Amazon Account.

Comment: Thanks a lot your metho worked for me. So not only I will accept your answer I will upvote it too. Hope will receive future help again

Comment: As a gift from me ( Jitendra Singh (the question asker)) here is a 50 bounty for making my tab work properly